# Which overloaded version of operator will be called

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

Suppose i have declared subscript operators in a class

1. `char& operator[] (int index);`
2. `const char operator[](int index) const;`

In what condition the second overload is called. Is it only called through a `const object`.

In the following scenarios which version of operator will be called.

```
const char res1 = nonConstObject[10]; 
nonConstObject[10];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first one is called. Don't get confused by the return value; only the arguments are considered to select the method. In this case, the implicit `this` is non-const, so the non-const version is called.

Answer (score -1):

Constant methods can only be called from constant instances.  Since nonConstObject isn't defined as const then both calls will be to the non-const overloaded operator.

Comment: Non-const methods can only be called for non-const instances.  But const methods can be called for bot const and non-const instances.